# JPA: How to fetch one entity's children given ID of other entity in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a many-to-many relationship from an entity to itself.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MERCHANTS")
public class Merchant {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<Service> services;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "SUB_MERCHANTS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "submerchant_id") })
  private final Set<Merchant> submerchants = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "submerchants")
  private final Set<Merchant> merchants = new HashSet<>();

}
```

In other words, a merchant can have many submerchants. Each merchant can have zero, one, or more services.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICES")
public class Service {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id")
  private Merchant merchant;

  // ...

}
```

The following query will give me all of a merchant's services given that merchant's ID.

```
SELECT s FROM Service s WHERE s.merchantId = :merchantId ORDER BY s.name ASC
```

If that merchant has submerchants, how can I also include each submerchant's services in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HQL query should return the results you need:

```
SELECT s from Service s where s.id in 
(SELECT sm_s.id FROM Merchant m JOIN m.submerchants sm JOIN sm.services sm_s WHERE m.id = :merchantId) 
or s.id in 
(select ms.id from Merchant m2 JOIN m2.services ms WHERE m2.id = :merchantId)
```